# Stylize Field based on Boolean value

Tags: views, entities

In Views showing as a table, I have 3 fields, field_checkbox1, field_checkbox2 and field_checkbox3,  and values set to either Yes or No. 
I need to add color to them, if the checkbox is set to Yes(on, checked, "1" or any other value that denotes a positive value that Drupal recognizes) the border of its  should be set to "2px solid #00ff00".
*****************************EDIT******************************

Which css file (there are 6) governs class="views-field views-field-field-checkbox1 green"? How Macro do I have to get?

Comment: please tell us your Drupal version, 7 or 8?

Comment: I am running version 7.50

Comment: Okay, edited. I can't make it any clearer without having you go to abcmouse.com.

Answer (score 2):

Add class to views (Advance -> Class) and then through css, do something like this:

`.className .Alpha["value=1"]{
      border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
.className .Alpha["value=0"]{
     border: 2px solid #f00;
}`

Value may slightly differ and you can simply check it through "inspect" of your browser's contextual menu.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using Drupal 8:**

Click on your boolean field, and click on REWRITE RESULTS

Checkmark ☑ Override the output of this field with custom text

On the text box put:

```
{% if field_name == 'yes' %}
  <div class="green">{{ field_name }}</div>
{% else %}
  {{ field_name }}
{% endif %}
```

Click on replacement patterns, to see the pattern/token you can use. You will only see patterns/tokens that are from the field, or arranged above the field.

[More info about Twig If Statements](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)

Comment: This is a better solution

Comment: As per the Twig-part of your answer, I assume it works for D8. But also for D7?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a Drupal 7 solution:**

Use the [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module

Add Views Conditional as a field. Make sure your boolean field is arranged above the Views Conditional field, other wise, it won't show up as an option.

Then set condition, if field_name is equal to `yes`

Then output this...

```
<div class="green">[field_name]</div>
```

Otherwise, output this...

`[field_name]`

Comment: For some unknown reason, I can't get this to work. I have tried [field_name] [field_name-value] even tried (Content: name).

Comment: If your Yes, has capital Y make sure it's like that. Else, you could try equal to `1`